# Chrome browser crashed after a file download opens in a new tab while running a selenium script

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

When the selenium script clicks on a link ,it opens a new tab which downloads a excel file, then chrome browser crashes/closes and subsequent steps fails. The same test script runs fine in firefox browser. There is no stack trace/log as what caused the crash.

```
            final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
            //chromePrefs.put(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_VERBOSE_LOG_PROPERTY, true);
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", getDownloadPath());
            Map<String, Object> perfLogPrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            perfLogPrefs.put("traceCategories", "browser,devtools.timeline,devtools");
            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("perfLoggingPrefs", perfLogPrefs);
            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            // chromeOptions.addArguments("--verbose");

            chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-logging");
            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--v=1");
            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            logger.info(chromeOptions.getExperimentalOption("perfLoggingPrefs"));
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();

            // chromeOptions.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
            if (headless) {
                // chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

            }
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

            ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(driverService, capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

No resolution yet, but you can follow the chromedriver bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2730